# boto 2.41 - set_contents_from_filename() fails when I use it to print upload progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto

I tried to upload a file into AWS using the following snippet of code.

```
filePath = os.path.join(output_dir, fileToUpload)
k = bucket.new_key(os.path.join(bucket_dir,fileToUpload))
k.set_contents_from_filename(filePath,cb=mycb, num_cb=10,policy='public-read')
```

As seen above I am using the call back feature(cb=mycb) to print the status of the upload. The upload fails with the following error:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

But when I remove the callback parameter from the set_contents_from_filename() func call, it works fine.

```
k.set_contents_from_filename(filePath ,policy='public-read')
```

Has anyone ever faced such an issue. Any thoughts on why the issue occurs?